# How to the change php settings from php code?

Tags: php, settings

I want to change the php setting but from ".php" page not php.ini. The settings I want to change is

`upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one of those that can be changed from within PHP is the last one, which can be changed with [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) like this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```

PHP always processes the client request before the PHP script is started. This means that uploaded files are already uploaded and posted forms are already fully posted beforeb he script starts. The upload and post settings can therefore not be set in the script, ebcause they are already irrelevant when the PHP script is started.

Comment: And the file uploads will probably be limited by the webserver config too.

Answer (score 3):

You can try it with a .htaccess file, if you have AllowOverride Options:

Place a file named .htaccess to your webroot:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10000
php_value post_max_size 10000
php_value memory_limit 10000
```

Comment: Hah! Forgot this possibility. Not always available either in shared hosting, but worth a try. +1

Comment: can you please tell me where to put this .htaccess. I mean you webroot, but confused in public_html\ or www\ or on the folder executing the script like public_html\uploads\

Comment: You can place it in any folder below the webroot. Put it next to your index.php file and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If your server administrator hasn't prevented it, you can use [`ini_set()`](http://www.php.net/ini_set) to change the memory limit:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","16000000"); // abbreviations like "16M" work only 
                                    // in php.ini, always use full numbers here
```

The two other options are needed before the PHP script is loaded, there is no way to change those in php.ini.

Comment: then how can i change them, my control panel does not give me the option to change php.ini settings

but i need to upload files larger than 100MB

Comment: @Starx sorry, there is probably no way to do this if you don't have access to `php.ini`. You'll have to talk to your provider or server administrator and ask them to increase the limit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ini_set ('key', 'value');
```

Note that not all the available options can be changed using ini_set(). Here'is a list: [ini.list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php)

Read more in [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) reference;