# How to change php setting from php file?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to the change php settings from php code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817804/how-to-the-change-php-settings-from-php-code)

I want to change the php setting but from ".php" page not php.ini. The settings I want to change is

`upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`